# Why can I close the style tag from inside CSS comments?

Tags: html, css

Why <\style> in comments is breaking embedded styles?
I thought I could write there whatever I want!

```
<!doctype html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>test</title>

<style>

/*
</style>
<h1>HTML!</h1>
<style>
*/

</style>
```

You can see it in action [here](http://ser-gen.github.io/sandbox/tests/test-cssComments.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTML is parsed first. This is why you might see `<\/b>` in JavaScript that works with HTML: older browsers used `</` as the "end of script block" marker (newer ones specifically look for `</script>`).

So the HTML is parsed, and the result is two `<style>` elements, one with a starting comment and the other with an ending comment.

If you need comments like that, consider using HTML comments:

```
<style><!--
    /* Whatever you want here! */
--></style>
```

All being well, this should allow the stylesheet to be parsed correctly.

Comment: Only `</style>` holds any meaning inside a `<style>` element. `<!-- -->` is garbage (there are some special parsing rules to handle it so that you can avoid having the CSS rendered as text in browsers that predate the `<style>` element). There is no way to comment out a `</style>` inside a style element.